# Btrfs volume missing

Tags: btrfs, raid6

I have an Ubuntu 64-bit Server with 7 4TB HDD's in a Btrfs Raid 6. A few days ago I executed the btrfs balance command but forgot that this takes quite a while. 'Cause of an update, I restarted my system while the balance was still being worked on. Now I'm only seeing the directory /dev/md0 but the mounting directory has always been /dev/md0p1 before, which is now missing. If I try the recover command on /md0 it can't find any btrfs volume.

How can I recover my data?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out myself. 
The Problem was my corrupted Raid. Only 5 out of 6 Devices were addressed in my mdadm.conf. 
I readded the HDD and the rebuild began automatically.
By now everything works fine.